# Electromagnetic waves and their extremes

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Why do we have electromagnetic waves only in the wave lengths between 10^2 to 10^-14 metres respectively from radio to gamma waves.? Does any scientific reason exist for that?
If it is not so, Does any other waves exist in the extremes of those both. Does gravitational waves belong to electromagnetic waves.,?

Comment: Btw: 10^2 and 10^2 has no meaning unless you specify the units. Are you talking about meters?

Comment: Sorry they are metres

Comment: I can make electromagnetic waves with arbitrarily long wavelength for you. Just let me know how long it should be. You want a light year? Not a problem. $10^{-14}m$ is only something like 100MeV. High energy physicist aren't even getting up in the morning for 100MeV, anymore.

Comment: I have heard that only India, USA, Russia produce electromagnetic waves of wave length more than 100 kilometres or so, do we have any big use from these.# Curious one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no physical principle that á priori restricts the range of possible wavelengths of electromagnetic radiation.

However, the higher the frequency the more energetic the radiation will be, so it will be harder to make that kind of radiation.

As for low frequency you can also have as long a wavelength as you wish.  In fact, you can think of a static electric field as roughly the limit of the wavelength going to infinity.

Finally: No, gravitational waves are NOT electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: @sreekara you will find this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_low_frequency) useful

Comment: Then to what category does gravitational waves belong to?

Comment: @sreekara gravitational waves are distortions in the space-time metric https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave. They also propagate with speed $c$ though.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to gravitational waves, no we have not determined them to be EM waves. Although we can't completely rule it out. For example, there is a theory that reconciles EM force with weak nuclear, and it is called [Electroweak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction). Electroweak interactions happen above 100 GeV, when EM and weak nuclear become the same force.

**Edit:** Maybe someone will develop a theory that unifies gravity and EM as the same force. Meanwhile, this [page](http://www.tapir.caltech.edu/~teviet/Waves/differences.html) from CalTech might help answer your gravity wave question.

Comment: Does cosmic waves have any relationship with gravitational waves.?# M Barbosa

Comment: @sreekara cosmic radiation is high energy radiation that comes from deep space. However, this radiation is actually made up of particles as big as protons, so I wouldn't say that they are EM. Although I am not sure they are grav waves either. Sorry I don't have more info on the particular subject.